# Meteor 0.8.0 <{{tag}}> Tag helper for html gives errors

Tags: meteor

Just trying to fix errors in [ogno-admin](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-ogno-admin) package to work with the new Meteor 0.8.0 update. It has a 'tag' help to dynamically assign tags. Here is the code:

Template code:

```
   {{#each mainItem}}
    <{{{tag}}} href="{{url}}" class="{{isActive}} header main item">
        <i class="{{icon}} icon"></i>
        {{menu-title}}
    </{{{tag}}} >
        {{#each subItem}}
        <a href="{{subUrl}}" class="{{isActive ../this}} item">{{menu-title}}</a>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

javascript:

'tag' : function () {
    return this['no-link'] || _.isArray(this.type) ? 'div' : 'a';
}
It give the following error:

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package ogno-admin:
menu/menu.html:6: Expected tag name after <
...nItem}} <{{{tag}}} href="{{ur...
^

Can anyone please shed some light on how to fix it?

Will really appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Praney

Comment: the [documentation has an example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#html-must-be-well-formed) of how tags can be set reactively.

Comment: Thanks mate looking at it

Comment: Ok I figured it can't be done in Spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

Tag names can no longer be dynamic in meteor 0.8.0.

Check out the updated docs. [Spacebars README](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars)